# Laravel Collection Filter doesn't return an Array as needed

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, rest, collections

I'm building a REST API and I need to return the TEAMS according to a certain EVENT which are not included in the EventScores table.
The problem I got is in the filtering. If $teams is modified by the ´filter´, the method returns something like this:

```
{
"1": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "sunt",
    "ath1": "Prof. Jarvis Rutherford",
    "ath2": "Joey Gutmann",
    "box": "ut",
    "category_id": 1,
    "totalScore": 6,
    "created_at": "2018-01-11 18:22:13",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-11 19:47:21"
}}
```

Otherwise, It returns an ARRAY which is what I need to get in orden make stuff in the front end. Here's is the sample of what I need:

```
[
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "eaque",
    "ath1": "Prof. Trever Grady",
    "ath2": "Angel Walsh",
    "box": "voluptatem",
    "category_id": 1,
    "totalScore": 15,
    "created_at": "2018-01-11 18:22:13",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-11 19:47:21"
}]
```

And this is the method:

```
public function eventTeams($category_id, $event_id)
{   
    $teams = Team::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();
    $eventScores = EventScores::where('event_id','=', $event_id)->get();
    $teams = $teams->filter(function($team) use($eventScores)
    {     
        if($eventScores->contains('team_id', $team->id)){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }

    });
    return response($teams, 200);
}
```

I've tried this: `$teamsArr = $teams->toArray()` and return $teamsArr but It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to query data throw relations like this:

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public function eventScores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EventScores');
    }
}

class EventScores extends Model
{
    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team');
    }
}

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $eventId = 1;
        $categoryId = 1;
        $teams = Team::whereHas('eventScores', function ($query) use ($eventId) {
            $query->where('event_id', $eventId);
        })->where('category_id', $categoryId)
            ->get();
        return response()->json($teams);
    }
}
```

or just use foreach instead filter:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($teams as $team) {
    if ($team->category_id == $categoryId) {
        $result[] = $team;
    }
}
return response()->json($result);
```

Comment: This worked! I had to use `whereDoesntHave` instead of `whereHas` to get what I was looking for but this was the way to go! Thanks @IncOre

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it doesn't work" what do you mean? Do you receive an error?

You can also do like this:

```
public function eventTeams($categoryId, $eventId)
{   
    $teams = Team::where('category_id', $categoryId)->get();

    $eventScoreTeamIds = EventScores::where('event_id', $eventId)
            ->get() // this will return a collection
            ->pluck('team_id') // get only the team_id
            ->all(); // get results as array

    $teams = $teams->filter(function($team) use($eventScoreTeamIds) {
        return in_array($team->id, $eventScoreTeamIds);     
    });

    return response($teams, 200);
}
```

Comment: What I mean with 'doesn't work' is that if $teams gets filtered, it returns an object with this format `{{"1": {"id": 6,"name": "sunt"}}}`; otherwise when the filter returns true for every element the final variable $teams is an array like [{...},{...}] and that's what I need to get in order to do a forEach in the JS front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values` method like this:

```
$teams = array_values(
    $teams->filter(function ($team) use ($eventScores) {
        return ! ($eventScores->contains('team_id', $team->id));
    })
);
```